# Improve table readability

Tags: tables

I would like to have an easily readable table. I did 2 computations for each of the two data sets A and B. I get three output parameters per computation that depends on 3 input models.

Ideally this would be a small table only using half the page (column-width). Otherwise text width at the top of the page is fine. I'm looking forward to your ideas. I couldn't find anything on tex overflow that helped me with this table.

What should come across is the comparison of column 1 to column 2 (slight tweak to the model has the impact xx on the parameters x,y,z. And comparison of columns 3 to 4. Then one wants to compare each column in order to compare the two data sets.

Thanks!

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}    % Advanced maths commands
\usepackage{amssymb}    % Extra maths symbols
\usepackage{multicol}        % Multi-column entries in tables
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 right=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 bottom=20mm
 }
\begin{document}

\Blindtext

\begin{table*}\centering
{\def\arraystretch{1.1}\tabcolsep=4pt
\begin{tabular}{@{}lccccc@{}}\hline\hline
Data set& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Data A } & \phantom{abc}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Data B} \\ \cline{2-3} \cline{5-6} 
\multirow{3}{*}{Models} 
&Model1 ($x>29$)& Model1  ($x>29$)& &Model1 ($x>29$)& Model1 ($x>29$)\\
& Model2 ($2\leq x \leq 29$)& Model2 ($11\leq x \leq 29$)&& Model2 ($2\leq x \leq 29$)& Model2 ($11\leq x \leq 29$)\\
& Model3.a ($2\leq x \leq 29$)& Model3.b ($2\leq x \leq 10$)&& Model3.a ($2\leq x \leq 29$)& Model3.b ($2\leq x \leq 10$)\\\midrule
x       & $0.1^{+0.005}_{-0.006}$ &$0.2^{+0.006}_{-0.007}$&&$0.15\pm 0.007$ &$0.25^{+0.006}_{-0.005}$ \\
y       & $3\pm 0.02$ &$3.^{+0.01}_{-0.01}$              &&$3.\pm 0.02$ &$3.\pm 0.01$ \\
z       & $7\pm 0.1$ &$7\pm 0.1$          &&$7\pm 0.3$ &$   8.\pm 0.1$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\caption{Parameter constraints from three different models (Model1, Model2, Model3). For model 3 we consider the base model 3.a and an extension model 3.b. The parameter x denotes the range of values that we are using for each model. The output of the computations are the summary statistic x, y and z. We perform the same operations on both data sets A and B.}
\label{tab:tab_test}
\end{table*}

\Blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your table code fragment to complete small document (beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`), which reproduce your problem.  Readability of table content is strong depended from page layout, so not knowing it, is hard to help you.

Comment: Off-topic: meaning of your column headers is meaningles (at least for me). Also you now change `table*` to `table`. Does your document really has one column with default pagel ayout?

Comment: No, the layout is from the journal and given as a two-column document. It would be too cumbersome to include that so I think that way is a MWE for everyone to reproduce.

Comment: @Than please correct your MWE accordingly. Use `\documentclass` of your real document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see plenty of room for improvements.

For uncertainty, symmetric or not, I propose a command `\data` that receives as arguments the main number and then the uncertainty; if there is a middle optional argument, this means asymmetric uncertainty.

The “models” can be typeset in nested tabulars, so we can align the data.

We can avoid guessing at `\tabcolsep` by using `tabular*`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}    % Advanced maths commands
\usepackage{amssymb}    % Extra maths symbols
\usepackage{multicol}        % Multi-column entries in tables
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
% left=20mm,
% right=20mm,
% top=20mm,
% bottom=20mm
 }
%\usepackage{xparse}% uncomment for LaTeX prior to 2020-10-01

\NewDocumentCommand{\data}{mom}{%
  \ensuremath{%
    #1\IfNoValueTF{#2}{\pm#3}{_{-#2}^{+#3}}%
  }%
}



\begin{document}

\Blindtext

\begin{table*}
\centering

\newcommand{\Models}[1]{% local command
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{\ }l@{}}#1\end{tabular}%
}


\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l*{4}{@{}c}@{}}
\toprule
Data set &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Data A} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Data B} \\
\cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5}
Models &
\Models{
  Model1   & ($x>29$) \\
  Model2   & ($2\leq x \leq 29$) \\
  Model3.a & ($2\leq x \leq 29$)
} &
\Models{
  Model1   & ($x>29$) \\
  Model2   & ($11\leq x \leq 29$) \\
  Model3.b & ($2\leq x \leq 10$)
} &
\Models{
  Model1   & ($x>29$) \\
  Model2   & ($2\leq x \leq 29$) \\
  Model3.a & ($2\leq x \leq 29$)
} &
\Models{
  Model1   & ($x>29$)\\
  Model2   & ($11\leq x \leq 29$)\\
  Model3.b & ($2\leq x \leq 10$)
} \\
\midrule
$x$ & \data{0.1}[0.006]{0.005} & \data{0.2}[0.007]{0.006}
    & \data{0.1}{0.007} & \data{0.25}[0.005]{0.006} \\
\addlinespace
$y$ & \data{3}{0.02} & \data{3.}[0.01]{0.01} & \data{3.}{0.02} & \data{3.}{0.01} \\
\addlinespace
$z$ & \data{7}{0.1}  & \data{7}{0.1}         & \data{7}{0.3}   & \data{8}{0.1} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\caption{Parameter constraints from three different models (Model1, Model2, Model3). 
  For model 3 we consider the base model 3.a and an extension model 3.b. The parameter 
  $x$ denotes the range of values that we are using for each model. The output of the 
  computations are the summary statistic x, y and z. We perform the same operations 
  on both data sets A and B.}
\label{tab:tab_test}
\end{table*}

\Blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext


\end{document}
```

[image]

You can get a more compact output by removing the repetitions.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}    % Advanced maths commands
\usepackage{amssymb}    % Extra maths symbols
\usepackage{multicol}        % Multi-column entries in tables
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
% left=20mm,
% right=20mm,
% top=20mm,
% bottom=20mm
 }
%\usepackage{xparse}% uncomment for LaTeX prior to 2020-10-01

\NewDocumentCommand{\data}{mom}{%
  \ensuremath{%
    #1\IfNoValueTF{#2}{\pm#3}{_{-#2}^{+#3}}%
  }%
}



\begin{document}

\Blindtext

\begin{table*}
\centering

\newcommand{\Models}[1]{% local command
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{\ }l@{}}#1\end{tabular}%
}


\begin{tabular}{@{}l*{4}{c}@{}}
\toprule
Data set &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Data A} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Data B} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
Models &
\Models{
  1   & ($x>29$) \\
  2   & ($2\leq x \leq 29$) \\
  3.a & ($2\leq x \leq 29$)
} &
\Models{
  1   & ($x>29$) \\
  2   & ($11\leq x \leq 29$) \\
  3.b & ($2\leq x \leq 10$)
} &
\Models{
  1   & ($x>29$) \\
  2   & ($2\leq x \leq 29$) \\
  3.a & ($2\leq x \leq 29$)
} &
\Models{
  1   & ($x>29$)\\
  2   & ($11\leq x \leq 29$)\\
  3.b & ($2\leq x \leq 10$)
} \\
\midrule
$x$ & \data{0.1}[0.006]{0.005} & \data{0.2}[0.007]{0.006}
    & \data{0.1}{0.007} & \data{0.25}[0.005]{0.006} \\
\addlinespace
$y$ & \data{3}{0.02} & \data{3.}[0.01]{0.01} & \data{3.}{0.02} & \data{3.}{0.01} \\
\addlinespace
$z$ & \data{7}{0.1}  & \data{7}{0.1}         & \data{7}{0.3}   & \data{8}{0.1} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Parameter constraints from three different models (Model1, Model2, Model3). 
  For model 3 we consider the base model 3.a and an extension model 3.b. The parameter 
  $x$ denotes the range of values that we are using for each model. The output of the 
  computations are the summary statistic x, y and z. We perform the same operations 
  on both data sets A and B.}
\label{tab:tab_test}
\end{table*}

\Blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ```\usepackage{xparse}``` missing in the post. How can I align all the + and - signs vertically irrespective if its \pm or ^{+}_{-}? very good solution, I like that. Thanks!

Comment: @AstroCoding2019 It's not needed with LaTeX 2020-10-01 or later. I'll add it with a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The following might serve as a place to start from.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}lllll@{}}
\toprule
Data set& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Data A } &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Data B} \\ \cmidrule(r){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5} 
Models 
&LONGNAME ABC & LONGNAME ABC  &LONGNAME ABC & LONGNAME ABC \\
& ($x>29$) & ($x>29$) & ($x>29$) & ($x>29$)\\
\addlinespace
& LONGNAME DEF & LONGNAME DEF & LONGNAME DEF & LONGNAME DEF \\
& ($2\leq x \leq 29$) & ($11\leq x \leq 29$)& ($2\leq x \leq 29$) & ($11\leq x \leq 29$)\\
\addlinespace
& LONGNAME HIJ1.0 & LONGNAME HIJ2.0 & LONGNAME HIJ1.0 & LONGNAME HIJ2.0 \\
& ($2\leq x \leq 29$) & ($2\leq x \leq 10$)& ($2\leq x \leq 29$) & ($2\leq x \leq 10$)\\
\midrule
x       & $0.1^{+0.005}_{-0.006}$ &$0.2^{+0.006}_{-0.007}$&$0.15\pm 0.007$ &$0.25^{+0.006}_{-0.005}$ \\
\addlinespace
y       & $3\pm 0.02$ &$3.^{+0.01}_{-0.01}$              &$3.\pm 0.02$ &$3.\pm 0.01$ \\
\addlinespace
z       & $7\pm 0.1$ &$7\pm 0.1$          &$7\pm 0.3$ &$   8.\pm 0.1$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Test}
\label{tab:tab_test}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. This looks good although, I find the table still quite big with 12 times "LONGNAME ... (2<x<10)". Do you have an idea on how to improve that? It's a huge and bulky table for not much information.

Comment: To be honest, without knowing what "LONGNAME HIJ" and the like actually stand for, I can't really help you with this. Probably you could use abbreviations for the individual models, use the abbreviation in the table and explain it in a (set of) table notes right below the table to avoid repetition. Probably, and again strongly depending on the context, a more visual representation of the mentioned intervals could be useful?

Comment: LONGNAME ABC, LONGNAME DEF, LONGNAME HIJ1.0 and LONGNAME HIJ2.0 are 4 different models that I'm using. HIJ2.0 is the extension of HIJ1.0. LONGNAME ABC is repeated 4 times since it is used 4 times the same way. LONGNAME DEF is used 4 times but with two different configurations (look at x constraints). LONGNAME HIJ1.0 is used twice and LONGNAME HIJ2.0 analogous. The length of the actual model name corresponds to the number of characters in LONGNAME ABC (to have a matching size of the table)

Comment: After OP edit the question seems that document is one column with default `article` layout (meaning even less space for table). OP should clarify this. BTW, column headers are not clear what they meaning. OP should consider to reorganise table.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Is that easier to understand (please see edits in original post)?

Answer (score 0):

Based on guessing (provided informations are confusing). So I limited only to some LaTeX aspect of your table design:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,
          total={170mm,257mm},
           margin=20mm
           }
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{booktabs, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
    \centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} lCCCC @{}}
    \toprule
Data set    
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Data A } 
            &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Data B}  \\ 
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
    \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
\multirow{3}{*}{Models}
    &   Model 1 ($x>29$)\par
        Model 2 ($2\leq x \leq 29$)\par
        Model 3 ($2\leq x \leq 29$)
        &   Model 1 ($x>29$)\par
            Model 2 ($11\leq x \leq 29$)\par
            Model 3a  ($2\leq x \leq 10$)
            &   Model2 ($x>29$)\par
                Model 2 ($2\leq x \leq 29$)\par
                Model 3b ($2\leq x \leq 29$)
                    &   Model 1 ($x>29$)\par
                        Model 2 ($11\leq x \leq 29$)\par
                        Model 3c  ($2\leq x \leq 10$) \\
    \midrule
x   &   $0.1^{+0.005}_{-0.006}$ 
        &   $0.2^{+0.006}_{-0.007}$
            &   $0.15\pm 0.007$ 
                &   $0.25^{+0.006}_{-0.005}$        \\
    \addlinespace
y   &   $3\pm 0.02$ 
        &   $3.^{+0.01}_{-0.01}$              
            &   $3.\pm 0.02$ 
                &   $3.\pm 0.01$                    \\
    \addlinespace
z   &   $7\pm 0.1$ 
        &   $7\pm 0.1$          
            &   $7\pm 0.3$ 
                &   $8.\pm 0.1$                     \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \caption{Test}
\label{tab:tab_test}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines show excerpt of the page layout)

**Edit:**
or with use of `\makecell` defined in the `makecell` package:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,
          total={170mm,257mm},
           margin=20mm
           }
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
    \centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} lCCCC @{}}
    \toprule
Data set    
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Data A } 
            &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Data B}  \\ 
    \cmidrule(r){2-3}
    \cmidrule{4-5}
Models
    &   \makecell[l]{Model 1 ($x>29$)\\
        Model 2 ($2\leq x \leq 29$)\\
        Model 3 ($2\leq x \leq 29$)}
        &  \makecell[l]{Model 1 ($x>29$)\\
            Model 2 ($11\leq x \leq 29$)\\
            Model 3a  ($2\leq x \leq 10$)}
            &   \makecell[l]{Model2 ($x>29$)\\
                Model 2 ($2\leq x \leq 29$)\\
                Model 3b ($2\leq x \leq 29$)}
                    &   \makecell[l]{Model 1 ($x>29$)\\
                        Model 2 ($11\leq x \leq 29$)\\
                        Model 3c  ($2\leq x \leq 10$)} \\
    \midrule
x   &   $0.1^{+0.005}_{-0.006}$ 
        &   $0.2^{+0.006}_{-0.007}$
            &   $0.15\pm 0.007$ 
                &   $0.25^{+0.006}_{-0.005}$        \\
    \addlinespace
y   &   $3\pm 0.02$ 
        &   $3.^{+0.01}_{-0.01}$              
            &   $3.\pm 0.02$ 
                &   $3.\pm 0.01$                    \\
    \addlinespace
z   &   $7\pm 0.1$ 
        &   $7\pm 0.1$          
            &   $7\pm 0.3$ 
                &   $8.\pm 0.1$                     \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \caption{Test}
\label{tab:tab_test}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]